# Cannot SSH into VirtualBox Ubuntu VM using Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I'm running Windows 7 and have Ubuntu VirtualBox installed. I'm trying to `ssh` into Ubuntu from my Windows using Putty. I failed. I have tried the following:

1. I see that OpenSSH server is running and listening on port 22. I tried SSH localhost from Ubuntu and it was successful
2. In my VirtualBox network setting, I am using bridged adapter.
3. I cannot `ping` the the IP address of the Ubuntu server from my host, but when I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on my Ubuntu box, I was able to access http://ubuntu_ip:8000/ from my Windows host's web browser
4. I created public and private key and stored the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
5. `iptables -L` results in:

   ```
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

   target     prot opt source               destination
   ```

I guess keys doesn't matter at this point because Putty is reporting:

```
2015-09-21 14:49:14 Failed to connect to x.x.227.235: Network error: Connection timed out
```

The fact that my host's browser can reach the VM that shows the proxy is bypassed. But why can't putty connect to it?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your Windows firewall blocking putty? Or antivirus?

Comment: Please post the routing tables of host and guest